# GraphQl - how to add current user to mutation object

Tags: graphql, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am attempting to add the current user to a `create` mutation by decorating graphql stages as per [the documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#workflow-of-the-resolvers).

It is a feature to allow users to block other users in a message system, fyi.

It should satisfy the following access control:

`"access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') and object.getBlocker() == user"`

Meaning that the user that is blocking is the currently authenticated user.

I can get it done if I modify the above to just:

`"access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"`
by decorating the `deserialize stage` like so:

App/Stage/DeserializeStage

```
/**
 * @param object|null $objectToPopulate
 *
 * @return object|null
 */
public function __invoke($objectToPopulate, string $resourceClass, string $operationName, array $context)
{
    // Call the decorated serialized stage (this syntax calls the __invoke method).
    $deserializeObject = ($this->deserializeStage)($objectToPopulate, $resourceClass, $operationName, $context);

    if ($resourceClass === 'App\Entity\BlockedUser' && $operationName === 'create') {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $deserializeObject->setBlocker($user);
    }

    return $deserializeObject;
}
```

As I understand it, in order to get it to work fully satisfying the access control, I would need to decorate the `read stage`, which comes before the `security stage` and insert the currently authenticated user to the object.

In that way, it would satisfy the second portion of the access control, ie, 
`and object.getBlocker() == user`

I attempted to do it as follows, but I get a `NULL` object :

App/Stage/ReadStage

```
/**
 * @return object|iterable|null
 */
public function __invoke(?string $resourceClass, ?string $rootClass, string $operationName, array $context)
{
    $readObject = ($this->readStage)($resourceClass, $rootClass, $operationName, $context);

    var_dump($readObject->getBlocked()->getUsername()); // throws error 'method getBlocked on NULL

    if ($resourceClass === 'App\Entity\BlockedUser' && $operationName === 'create') {
        $userId = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $readObject->setBlocker($user);
    }

    return $readObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after restarting the app it seems to be working properly in the `deserialize` stage. It might have been an issue with cache or something.

I am still not sure why it works in the `deserialize` stage nor if that's the correct place to modify the object.

In any case, it is working as is, so...

So, I am posting the full code for reference.

App/Stage/DeserializeStage

```
<?php

namespace App\Stage;

use ApiPlatform\Core\GraphQl\Resolver\Stage\DeserializeStageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

final class DeserializeStage implements DeserializeStageInterface
{
private $deserializeStage;
/**
 * @var TokenStorageInterface
 */
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(
    DeserializeStageInterface $deserializeStage,
    TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->deserializeStage = $deserializeStage;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

/**
 * @param object|null $objectToPopulate
 *
 * @return object|null
 */
public function __invoke($objectToPopulate, string $resourceClass, string $operationName, array $context)
{
    // Call the decorated serialized stage (this syntax calls the __invoke method).
    $deserializeObject = ($this->deserializeStage)($objectToPopulate, $resourceClass, $operationName, $context);

    if ($resourceClass === 'App\Entity\BlockedUser' && $operationName === 'create') {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $deserializeObject->setBlocker($user);
    }

    return $deserializeObject;
}
}
```

And you need to add this to `config/services.yaml`

```
App\Stage\DeserializeStage:
    decorates: api_platform.graphql.resolver.stage.deserialize
```